# xampp installation error in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, xampp

After installation I am able to run this command

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

but whem try to run the following command

```
   sudo chmod 755 manager-linux-x64.run
   sudo ./manager-linux-x644.run
```

I get the following

> error::Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
>   keyUnknown Error couldn't connect to display ":0"